# AMP Webpush Error: 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, amp-html, web-push

So I'm trying to implement webpush notifications for an AMP page, following the official documentation:

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-web-push

But there is an issue when adding the `<amp-web-push>` component and specifying the `helper-iframe-url` that points to the `amp-web-push-helper-frame.html`, the one I've downloaded from the official page.

When I open my AMP page in browser, there are an error in the console:

> Refused to display
>   'https://mytestsite.com/test/amp/amp-web-push-helper-frame.html?parentOrigin=https://mytestsite.com'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

And regarding that, I cant interact with the service worker. I took a look at the official AMP demo and there's no `X-Frame-Options` header with  `deny` value.

This is my HTML templates:

AMP component:

```
<amp-web-push
        id="amp-web-push"
        layout="nodisplay"
        helper-iframe-url="https://mytestsite.com/test/amp/amp-web-push-helper-frame.html"
        permission-dialog-url="https://mytestsite.com/test/amp/amp-web-push-permission-dialog.html"
        service-worker-url="https://mytestsite.com/test/amp/service-worker.js">
</amp-web-push>
```

AMP widget

```
    <amp-web-push-widget visibility="unsubscribed" layout="fixed" width="245" height="45">
        <!-- Custom banner goes here... -->
    </amp-web-push-widget>
```

So I spent the whole day searching for solution and refactoring but still with the problem.

Comment: The X-Frame-Options header is defined by your backend server software or reverse proxy (nginx, apache, envoy, etc). You have to change it to X-Frame-Options: sameorigin.

Comment: Thanks, @filipe, it resolved my trouble! Now it works fine!

Comment: Well, solving the previous issue, a new one appeared... When the helper is loaded, have the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: module$build$all$amp_web_push_0_1$window_messenger is not defined`. So I going to search for solution.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, it was an error of my service worker, so now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X-Frame-Options header is defined by your backend server software or reverse proxy (nginx, apache, envoy, etc).

You have to change it to `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`.